# Autofixture: Issue when creating value types

Tags: autofixture

Debugging with xUnit.net the test-methods `Test1` and `Test2` of the following code and putting a breakpoint and the end of `CreateValueAndReferenceType()` you see that the variable `valueType` is the same in both runs, whereas the variable `referenceType` is altered. The former is for me surprising and an issue as well (I added the row with the string-type only for completeness).

```
public class MyFixture : Fixture
{
    public void CreateValueAndReferenceType()
    {
        var valueType = this.Create<int>();
        var referenceTye = this.Create<string>();
    }
}

public class TestClass1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var myFixture = new MyFixture();
        myFixture.CreateValueAndReferenceType();
    }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        var myFixture = new MyFixture();
        myFixture.CreateValueAndReferenceType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is, I think, a basic issue related to pseudo-random number generation in .NET (IIRC, other platforms have similar issues). In essence, `System.Random` is deterministic, but initialised with a random seed that, among other things, depend on the computer's current time. If you create instances of `Random` in a tight loop, the code executes faster than the precision of the system clock. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console.Write(new Random().Next(0, 9));
```

will often produce output like this:

```
5555555555
```

Most values in AutoFixture are generated by various `Random` instances - the exception is the `string` type, of which values are generated by `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

I *think* that the reason you're seeing this is because of xUnit.net's parallel execution.

In order to pinpoint the problem, I rephrased the issue so that it doesn't rely on debugging or inheritance:

```
public static class Reporter
{
    public static void CreateValueAndReferenceType(
        IFixture fixture,
        ITestOutputHelper @out)
    {
        var valueType = fixture.Create<int>();
        var referenceTye = fixture.Create<string>();

        @out.WriteLine("valueType: {0}", valueType);
        @out.WriteLine("referenceType: {0}", referenceTye);
    }
}

public class TestClass1
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper @out;

    public TestClass1(ITestOutputHelper @out)
    {
        this.@out = @out;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Reporter.CreateValueAndReferenceType(new Fixture(), this.@out);
    }
}

public class TestClass2
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper @out;

    public TestClass2(ITestOutputHelper @out)
    {
        this.@out = @out;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Reporter.CreateValueAndReferenceType(new Fixture(), this.@out);
    }
}
```

When you run this with the xUnit.net console runner, you can see the issue nicely reproduced:

```
$ packages/xunit.runner.console.2.1.0/tools/xunit.console 37925109/bin/Debug/Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.dll -diagnostics
-parallel all
xUnit.net Console Runner (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (app domain = on [shadow copy], method display = ClassAndMethod)
  Discovered:  Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (running 2 test cases)
  Starting:    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (parallel test collections = on, max threads = 4)
    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.TestClass2.Test2 [PASS]
      Output:
        valueType: 246
        referenceType: cc39f570-046a-4a0a-8adf-ab7deadd0e26
    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.TestClass1.Test1 [PASS]
      Output:
        valueType: 246
        referenceType: 87455351-03f7-4640-99fb-05af910da267
  Finished:    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109  Total: 2, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 0,429s
```

In the above example, you'll notice that I've *explicitly* invoked the runner with `-parallel all`, but I didn't have to do that, since it's the default.

If, on the other hand, you turn off parallelisation with `-parallel none`, you'll see that the values are different:

```
$ packages/xunit.runner.console.2.1.0/tools/xunit.console 37925109/bin/Debug/Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.dll -diagnostics
-parallel none
xUnit.net Console Runner (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (app domain = on [shadow copy], method display = ClassAndMethod)
  Discovered:  Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (running 2 test cases)
  Starting:    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (parallel test collections = off, max threads = 4)
    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.TestClass2.Test2 [PASS]
      Output:
        valueType: 203
        referenceType: 1bc75a33-5542-4d9f-b42d-57ed85dc418d
    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.TestClass1.Test1 [PASS]
      Output:
        valueType: 117
        referenceType: 6a508699-dc35-4bcd-8a7b-15eba64b24b4
  Finished:    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109  Total: 2, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 0,348s
```

What I think happens is that because of the parallelism, both `Test1` and `Test2` are executed in parallel, and essentially within the same tick.

One workaround is to place both tests in the same test class:

```
public class TestClass1
{
    private readonly ITestOutputHelper @out;

    public TestClass1(ITestOutputHelper @out)
    {
        this.@out = @out;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Reporter.CreateValueAndReferenceType(new Fixture(), this.@out);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Reporter.CreateValueAndReferenceType(new Fixture(), this.@out);
    }
}
```

This produces two different integer values, because (IIRC) xUnit.net only run different test *classes* in parallel:

```
$ packages/xunit.runner.console.2.1.0/tools/xunit.console 37925109/bin/Debug/Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.dll -diagnostics
-parallel all
xUnit.net Console Runner (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
  Discovering: Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (app domain = on [shadow copy], method display = ClassAndMethod)
  Discovered:  Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (running 2 test cases)
  Starting:    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109 (parallel test collections = on, max threads = 4)
    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.TestClass1.Test2 [PASS]
      Output:
        valueType: 113
        referenceType: e8c30ad8-f2c8-4767-9e9f-69b55c50e659
    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109.TestClass1.Test1 [PASS]
      Output:
        valueType: 232
        referenceType: 3eb60bf3-4d43-4a91-aef2-42f7e23e35b3
  Finished:    Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109
=== TEST EXECUTION SUMMARY ===
   Ploeh.StackOverflow.Q37925109  Total: 2, Errors: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Time: 0,360s
```

This theory is also corroborated by the fact that if you repeat the experiment sufficiently many times, you'll see the numbers being different once in a while. Here are the integer results from 25 test runs:

```
33  33
92  92
211 211
13  13
9   9
160 160
55  55
155 155
137 137
161 161
242 242
183 183
237 237
151 151
104 104
254 254
123 123
244 244
144 144
223 9
196 196
126 126
199 199
221 221
132 132
```

Notice that all except one test run has equal numbers.

Comment: a workaround could be:  this.Register<int>(() => (byte)Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

Comment: correction of my proposal:  *this.Register<int>(() => Math.Max((byte)1, (byte)Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()))*;